# update text after finding a specific string in column SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.2

i want to append a "TEXT" in column type of text in PostgreSQL database.
Text in the column is "Hello welcome to my page".

i want to append a text as "GuestName" after text "Hello";

Resulted output should be :
"Hello GuestName welcome to my page".

Thanks
sunil

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has the `overlay()` function:

```
select overlay('Hello welcome to my page' placing 'GuestName' || ' ' from 7 for 0)
```

If you are trying to make something generic, I would recommend `replace()` instead:

```
select replace('Hello [GuestName] welcome to my page',
               '[GuestName]', 'GuestName')
```

Setting up such a template gives you more flexibility in constructing the strings.

Answer (score 0):

replace(string text, from text, to text)

```
UPDATE <table> SET <field> = replace(<field>, 'Hello ', 'Hello GuestName')
```

or

```
SELECT replace(<field>, 'Hello ', 'Hello GuestName') FROM <table>
```

Comment: Thanks SAS , gone with UPDATE <table> SET <field> = replace(<field>, 'Hello ', 'Hello GuestName')

Comment: Please accept/vote for the solution(s) that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
update your_table set column_name = replace(column_name,'Hello','Hello GuestName') 
where column_name = 'Hello welcome to my page';
```